# Parse Golang variables

Tags: parsing, go, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm trying to static analyze Go files. For this I need to parse variables of the following format:

```
shape.color = color.red
```

I need to find all variables accessed with dot notation. For example, I need to know that shape variable has the color attribute. And also need that color variable has red attribute.
Im trying to use the go/ast and go/parser package but cant figure out a way to do it.

N.B. If it's something like shape.color() i.e, a method, then it shouldn't be counted

Comment: Can you show the code you've tried to do this and explain what issues specifically you've had with it?

Comment: You might have a good reason, but my first question is: Why are you reinventing the wheel? Why not use the standard Go parsing libraries from the Go project?

Comment: @Flimzy I was trying, but I couldn't. I was finally able to. I posted the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah! The following code prints all the variables accessed with dot notation!

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "go/ast"
    "go/parser"
    "go/token"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    v := visitor{}
    filename := "test.go"

    fset := token.NewFileSet()
    f, err := parser.ParseFile(fset, filename, nil, 0)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    ast.Walk(&v, f)
}

type visitor struct {
}

func (v *visitor) Visit(n ast.Node) ast.Visitor {
    if n == nil {
        return v
    }

    if selectorExp, ok := n.(*ast.SelectorExpr); ok {
        if x, ok := selectorExp.X.(*ast.Ident); ok {
            if x.Obj == nil {
                return v
            }  

            fmt.Printf("%s.%s\n", x.Name, selectorExp.Sel.Name)
        }
    }
    return v
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to create your own AST, as the right side of the expression you've given doesn't seem like a variable, otherwise I assume it as a struct. However, that's doesn't make sense too, since it'd be literally illogical to put a field named `red` in a struct named `color`. It also seems like you're trying to access a variable of a package but that also wouldn't work because lowercased first letter means that that the entity is unexported.

Leaving all them aside, I wrote a little snippet just to abide by the conditions you've listed.

- shape variable has the color attribute.
- color variable has red attribute.

---

https://play.golang.org/p/gIpctQ1XSgT, I adapted it just for a single line and panicked whenever conditions aren't met for brevity. Feel free to adjust it on your needs.

```
package main

import (
    "go/ast"
    "go/format"
    "go/parser"
    "go/token"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    expr, err := parser.ParseExpr("shape.color==color.red")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Checking if the expression was binary.
    bExpr, ok := expr.(*ast.BinaryExpr)
    if !ok {
        panic("expr is not a binary expr.")
    }

    // If the operation is not “==”, die.
    if bExpr.Op != token.EQL {
        panic("the op should have been ==.")
    }

    // Left must be a selector expr, meaning followed with a selector which is “dot” in this case.
    left, ok := bExpr.X.(*ast.SelectorExpr)
    if !ok {
        panic("left should have been a selector expr.")
    }

    // Same as above.
    right, ok := bExpr.Y.(*ast.SelectorExpr)
    if !ok {
        panic("right should have been a selector expr.")
    }

    // Checking for attributes.
    if left.Sel.Name != "color" {
        panic("left should have had a color attr.")
    }

    // Same as above.
    if right.Sel.Name != "red" {
        panic("right should have had a red attr.")
    }

    // Then we finally gofmt the code and print it to stdout.
    if err := format.Node(os.Stdout, token.NewFileSet(), expr); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are comparing two go variables that you do not know in advance you will need to use reflection.  This will allow you to reflectively compare the two fields:

```
type color struct {
    Red string
}

type shape struct {
    Color string
}

func main() {
    color := color{Red: "red"}
    shape := shape{Color: "red"}

    colorVal := reflect.ValueOf(color)
    shapeVal := reflect.ValueOf(shape)

    colorRedField := colorVal.FieldByName("Red")
    shapeColorField := shapeVal.FieldByName("Color")

    fmt.Println(colorRedField)
    fmt.Println(shapeColorField)
    fmt.Println(colorRedField.Interface() == shapeColorField.Interface())
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/gvTJYwStP1O